# How do I split the input into variable-length pieces without using recursion?

Tags: parsing, clojure

I have an input file with the following content:

```
2
stuff-11
stuff-12
3
stuff-21
stuff-22
stuff-23
1
stuff-31
```

I want to get the following result:

```
([stuff-11 stuff-12] [stuff-21 stuff-22 stuff-23] [stuff-31])
```

My initial solution was to use recursion with accumulator, like this:

```
(defn parse-input [lines accum]
   (if (= 0 (count lines))
       accum
       (let [[line-num (Integer. (first lines))]
             [head tail] (split-at (+ 1 line-num) lines)]
             [stuff (vec (drop 1 head))]]
            (parse-input tail (concat accum [stuff]))))
(def result (parse-input input []))
```

But, as far as I understand, recursive functions are not idiomatic in Clojure due to lack of TCO on JVM.

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: Mr. Borkent has the right approach. I'd also suggest that you look at `recur` and `loop` to implement Clojure's version of tail recursion.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to `recur` and `loop`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
user=> (require '[clojure.string :as s])
nil
user=> (require '[clojure.edn :as edn])
nil
user=> (keep-indexed #(if (odd? %) %2) 
                     (partition-by (comp number? edn/read-string) 
                     (s/split-lines (slurp "/tmp/input.txt"))))
(("stuff-11" "stuff-12") ("stuff-21" "stuff-22" "stuff-23") ("stuff-31"))
```

where `/tmp/input.txt` contains the text you provided.

Replace `#(if (odd? %) %2)` with `#(if (odd? %) (vec %2))` if you want to have a sequence of vectors as a result.

Comment: So, this solution ignores the fact, that the numbers specify, how many lines we should read, and just uses lines with numbers as delimeters. Very neat.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like Michiel Borkent's answer for several reasons, one of which is the fact that `((comp number? read-string) "3 blah blahb stuff and etc")` returns true. Also, while it may be concise, it's not terribly intuitive or extensible.

I think you had the right intuition to use recursion, but that a lazy seq is more idiomatic.

```
(defn parse-stuff [text]
  (let [step (fn step [[head & tail]]
               (when-let [n (clojure.edn/read-string head)] 
                 (cons (vec (take n tail))
                   (lazy-seq (step (drop n tail))))))]
     (step (clojure.string/split-lines text))))
```

Comment: You also use edn/read-string so, (parse-stuff "3 a b c\nstuff21") also gets parsed, just as in my solution.

Comment: eh, no. No it doesn't. At least not if the input if well-formed. I think it's fairly safe to say that this guy is solving codejam puzzles or something similar, so we're looking at the whole "line containing an inteter, N, followed by N lines containing a bunch of numbers too" thing. Look at his code, that's what it is doing.

Comment: Regarding extensibility, this solution can be easily extended, when we need to extract some more information from the lines with numbers. While Michiel Borkent's solution can be easily extended, when delimeters between sections are arbitrary. Both solution are extensible in their own sense. Regarding this solution: as far as I understood from reading docs, when one-time recursive function is required, `loop` and `recur` are more idiomatic, then defining local function with `let`.

Comment: Sorry, d.j.sheldrick, I somehow missed your reply. You are right, I was solving codejam puzzles. But my initial problem definition didn't reflect this (it didn't specify, that the other strings can also contain numbers). And I realized it only when I read Michael Borkent's answer. Of course, your solution is better for codejam-style inputs.